# Multiple python open read and write

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a program that takes in multiple body of texts an gives it a sentiment analysis score.

I have a separate web crawler that crawls per URL and parses the articles body and pass it into a function called **def articleGet(date, body)**

```
f_out = open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'r')
rowlen = len(f_out.readlines())

print(rowlen)

f_out = open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'a')
wr = csv.writer(f_out, lineterminator='\n')
#check if title columns exist
if(rowlen < 1):
    wr.writerow(OUTPUT_FIELDS)

output_data = get_data(body)
wr.writerow(output_data)
```

I want to create a csv file with this format

> date      |      score
>
> 11/28/17  |        4
>
> 11/20/17  |        5

Something like that. So I want to first read the OUTPUT_FILE, whether the title columns (date, score, etc) already exist before appending into the file. I am having trouble with this where this would work only if the .csv file already exist and is empty, but will not create another one if it does not exist

Comment: Simply open file in `a+` mode.

Comment: @GarbageCollector which open line? Or does it not matter? If I do it with the top, instead of `'r'`. Seems like it adds title, data, title, data... which is not what I want.

Comment: Why don't you just write the heading line outside of this function?